# Using a non-ID dynamic parameter with the ember router v2

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Has anyone messed around with using a non-ID parameter with the new ember router?

Back with the older version of the router, it seemed like an easier thing to do, since you had access to the serialize and deserialize methods on a route. In effect you could theoretically deserialize a non-ID attribute of the model into the params hash, and you could serialize an object from that non-ID attribute using the deserialize and serialize methods on the route, respectively. From my understanding the serialize and deserialize methods are no longer public, which makes this a bit trickier to handle..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the new router, you still have access to serialization and deserialization.

- `deserialize` has been renamed `model`, and it gets the params as a parameter. If you return an Ember Data object from `model` (or any other [Promises/A+ compatible promise](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec)), the rest of the hooks will not run until the object has loaded.
- `serialize` is still named `serialize`. It takes the model (the object passed to the `linkTo` helper or the `transitionTo` method) as its first argument, and should return a hash of parameters.

Comment: thanks again yehuda, i believe i probably owe you a six-pack by now.