# Non-id/permalink Dynamic routes with Ember-data and Fixtures

Tags: ember.js, url-routing, ember-data

So I'm trying to get my routing to work so that I have permalinks in my url for sharing. I.E. "/getting-started".

I can't seem to figure out how the model/serialize works, so how does ember-data know how to find my object with a string? I already did an attempt at the queryFixtures and it returns the right model but it isn't set

*Here is my code:*

### **Router:**

```
App.Router.map (match) -> 
  @resource 'topics', {path: "/support"}, ->
    @route 'topic', {path: '/:permalink'}

# Support Routes
App.TopicsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    this.store.find('topic')

App.TopicsTopicRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  # serialize: (model, params) ->
  #   return { topic_id: model.get(params.topic_id) }

  model: (param) ->
    @get('store').findQuery App.Topic, {permalink: param.permalink}

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set("content", model)

  actions:
     error: (error) ->
      console.log error



App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend
  queryFixtures: (fixtures, query, type) ->
    fixtures.filter (item) ->
      for property, value of query
        if item[property] == value
          return item
        else
          false
```

### **And my fixtures:**

```
App.Topic = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  permalink: DS.attr('string')
  position: DS.attr('number')


# Fiture data
App.Topic.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1
    name: "Getting Started"
    permalink: "getting-started"
    position: 1
    articles: [
      { name: "test 1", content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et." },
      { name: "test 2", content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et." },
      { name: "test 3", content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et." }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2
    name: "Frequently Asked Questions"
    permalink: "frequently-asked-questions"
    position: 2
    articles: [
      { name: "test 1", content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et." },
      { name: "test 2", content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et." }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3
    name: "Tips & Tricks"
    permalink: "tips-tricks"
    position: 3
    articles: [
      { name: "test 1", content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et." }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I will assume you're using the version 1.0.0 of Ember and the Beta version 1.0.0 of Ember Data.

For the router you described, you should setup the following Route objects:

```
App.TopicsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
```

and

```
App.TopicIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
```

otherwise Ember will have issues passing the correct model to the routes.

Now in the TopicIndexRoute (TopicsTopicRoute in your code) you use the model hook, which is called ONLY when entering the URL or reloading the page and NOT when coming to the route through the {{link-to}} helper (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model).

When you're going to the TopicIndexRoute from a {{link-to}} helper, the "ember magic" match the dynamic segment (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models) to the corresponding model only if it's the model's ID. I don't know how to solve this yet. This might help: [Using a non-ID dynamic parameter with the ember router v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313295/using-a-non-id-dynamic-parameter-with-the-ember-router-v2)

I don't know if the fixtures you're using are working but when setting relationships you should use (at least that's how it's shown in the guides: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_json-conventions) the model ID instead of declaring the instance. It would look like this:

```
App.Article.FIXTURES = [
{
 id: 1,
 name: "test 1",
 content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et."
},
{
 id: 2,
 name: "test 2",
 content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et."
},
{
 id: 3,
 name: "test 3",
 content: "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et."
}
]

App.Topic.FIXTURES = [
{
 id: 1
 name: "Getting Started"
 permalink: "getting-started"
 position: 1
 articles: [1,2,3]
}
]
```

I hope this helps you.